# How to make condition for queue?

Tags: anylogic

I want to make agents to not enter the queue if it's full (if it's full then go to sink) at the moment of arrival in selectOutput5.
I tried to put "if-else" into "Actions" section
[image]

But I don't really know which parameter to use (tried to use `queue.size` and `queue.capacity` but I don't know how to code this properly), please help. Not sure if I doing the right thing at all by trying to put if-else into actions of selectOutput5

The model look like this:

[image]

Comment: The Actions section is only for code you want to execute if they do exit one of the out options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to code the conditions under which they should enter which queue and then if the conditions are not met it will assess the next out option.

See example below

[image]

It will only go to queue 1 if the queue size is less than 5, else it will assess the queue size of queue 2 and if both are full then go to the exit.

The Actions section is only for code you want to execute if they do exit one of the out options.

Comment: I forgot to mention this: the agents must choose the queues by probabilities. So i have 0.3/0.5/0.5/0.2/0.2 on each queue and I was thinking where to put conditions to make them to not enter the queue if its full.

Comment: @rreskey See my updated example picture and some dummy values for the queue size, just replace it with your actual values. remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful and upvote if you think it serving ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Put a `selectOutputOut` block, select conditions there. And type below your condition: `yourQueue.size()>=yourQueue.capacity()`. Send the ones to `Sink` block when this condition is true.